# The Nature Letter Latex template

Tags: templates

Unfortunately in Nature website no any latex template is provided. 
Has anybody any template which is close to the Nature Letter style?

Comment: Did you read http://www.nature.com/nphys/authors/submit/index.html#TeX-LaTeX

Comment: As with any other journal, reproducing the printed style is a _waste of time_ unless they ask you to, and if they do they'll almost certainly provide a template. Journals typeset accepted papers themselves: that's not your job!

Comment: Agreeing with Joseph on this. If there is no specific template for you to use, use the standard `article` class, standard `10pt` and do not change the base font and do not change the margins. Use that as your basic template.

Comment: @JosephWright I know this is old, but when there's a page limit, reproducing the style can be effective in checking the length (many journals are set much tighter than the default `article` so the change could be significant).

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
\documentclass{nature}
```

?

Comment: OK, what about it ?

Comment: Provides Nature-like formatting as requested. Nothing else.

Comment: No that's wrong. Line numbers aren't included, figure descriptions aren't the way they are supposed to be, Nature's ordering isn't enforced simply by specifying a class, etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience using `\documentclass{nature}` , it works ok except for some problems with tables and figures alignment since the commands options `[htbp]` don´t work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I only know of the one provided by overleaf on the website of a competitor they bought (sharelatx): https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/nature

Seems they are using the template by Peter Czoschke from 2004: http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nature/nature-template.tex