# How to find a Nature Communications LaTeX template?

Tags: article, physics, scientific-workplace

Unfortunately, I do not succeed to find the Nature Communications template on internet. May be I am not looking in the right place, but only find indications on "how" to write.

Of course, I read [this question its simple answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226460/the-nature-letter-latex-template), and try to include this code at the beginning of the `.tex`:

```
\documentclass{nature}
```

The result does not look at all like what we can find when reading Nature Communications paper (for example, only one column and udge line spacing...).

**So, is there a kind of bank for Nature template, as there are a lot (and very easy to find) for PRL, PRX, PRB, etc... ?**

Thanks !

Comment: _Nature_ are really not focussed on LaTeX-based submission: their workflow is more Word ... From https://mts-ncomms.nature.com/cgi-bin/main.plex?form_type=display_auth_instructions: 'We can accept LaTeX files at the acceptance stage, but before then please supply compiled PDFs. '

Comment: @JosephWright : Thanks for your pertinent response, but I find so much easier to write with LaTeX. As they accept, is there a way to get a template?

Comment: Many publishing houses use some weird (and probably XML-based, yukes!) pipelines in their production. Things get converted to their internal formats anyway, in this sense there might be no 100% fitting LaTeX template for the final paper versions. What also happens quite often is that the submitted-for-review version should not be typeset in the final template, there are special "review" templates or basically anything looking like a manuscript is accepted. Regarding LaTeX, `article` class might already suffice.

Comment: They presumably? reset any text in their normal typesetting workflow so presumably any latex class would be Ok, just use `article`, there is no need to fake the layout of the published paper.

Comment: If the final published pdf is two-column, it would be a good idea to make sure that any display elements will fit within that width.  You're the author, so you will know better than any editor how best to present it so that it will be understood by a reader.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The instructions at https://www.nature.com/ncomms/submit/how-to-submit

say the following, note that they explicitly ask that you use a standard class and don't try to use some non standard macros to approximate the final layout.

> TeX/LaTeX — To submit a TeX/LaTeX file, please use any of the standard class files such as article.cls, revtex.cls or amsart.cls. All textual material should be provided as a single file in default Computer Modern fonts. Please avoid non-standard fonts and packages and remove all personal macros before submitting. For graphics, we recommend graphicx.sty. Please use numerical references only for citations, and include the references within the manuscript file itself.  If you wish to use BibTeX, please copy the reference list from the .bbl file, paste it into the main manuscript .tex file, and delete the associated \bibliography and \bibliographystyle commands. Before submission, please ensure that the complete .tex file compiles successfully on your own system with no errors or warnings. There is no need to spend time visually formatting the manuscript: our style will be imposed automatically when the paper is prepared for publication.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May be a simple Nature looking like template would be good to complete conclude this subject.

Comment: @AgapeGal'lo using anything other than the classes they suggest will complicate their conversion from the file that you send to the format they need. Thus will, I assume, make acceptance less likely. There is a reason they say "remove all personal macros". They want the tex as simple as possible as they do not use tex, so they need to extract the text from your submission.

Comment: I understand your answer, and I do think it's a pertinent one. Nevertheless, having a simple/light `.tex` which provide a kind of looking nature would be something liked (at least by me, and my lab).

Comment: What about using scientific report template which is already available online? https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scientific-reports/xyrztqvdccns

Is that considered personal macro?

Comment: @TravelingSalesman it complicates the work of the journal production staff so may delay or prohibit your article being published,

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will just use very standard class then and the formatting seems not my job especially at initial submission.

Comment: Sorry @David I have another question here, what about references? The page you provided link to states that there should be a format for the references last name, comma, then initial, but when I used standard package as you said it does not format it this way (I am using article class). If I have to change this then I will need to define my own way using .bst file.